# Convert a varchar(19) hexadecimal to decimal

Tags: sql, oracle

[image: Data in DB]

DB : Oracle 19

The above data is stored as HexaDecimal I think

But I am unable to convert to decimal

Comment: `G` and `{` are not hexadecimal characters. What do you think/expect those values represent?

Comment: Try in SQLDeveloper 's worksheet a command: `desc TABLE_NAME;` to get the basic description of the given table. You will get the list of columns and their data types. When you will be 100% sure of the source data type, then you can think of converting it to another.

Comment: @robertus, I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. Which datatype is supposed to contain hexadecimal data? There's no such datatype (if you meant to say that); as hexadecimal numbers contain both digits 0-9 and letters A-F, that's one of the CHAR *family* (CHAR, VARCHAR, VARCHAR2). And that won't help in converting that value into another datatype.

Comment: There is no way to know what you presented as sample data - SQL Developers allows custom formatting for the columns display. So the screenshot doesn't tell what kind of data you have. We can assume that it is a `varchar`, but what if it is `nvarchar` or `raw`? It's hard to give you correct and full answer without knowing some important facts. That's why I asked about what is the real data type of the column. It's worth to point out what Alex Pool said - `G` and `{` are not valid for hexadecimal, so something is wrong. It's good to cover all the basics and not to implicitly assume anything.

Comment: You asked: `Which datatype is supposed to contain hexadecimal data?` - I think that we should think of hexadecimal as only as the way of displaying - kind of the way of formatting data, not the data type per se. It's just a shorter way of displaying binary data  - one hexadecimal "digit" covers 4 bits, so for a full byte you need 2 characters. It is way easier to write in some doc that you should push `FF` to some register instead of `11111111`. So the answer for your question is: it depends on the use case - but raw, number or blob should be fine, and varchar is rather inefficient.